# Passing argument makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I wrote a function that looks like this:

```
- (void)changeText:(NSUInteger)arrayIndex;
```

Let's just say that's a method in the class Label.  Let's say I have an array of Label objects.  I call the function like this:

```
[[labels objectAtIndex:0] changeText:1];
```

or like this:

```
NSUInteger index = 1;
[[labels objectAtIndex:0] changeText:index];
```

Why does it give me the warning: `Passing argument 1 of 'changeText:' makes pointer from integer without a cast`?  The code executes fine.

****EDIT****

Calling the function these ways does not give a warning:

```
[[labels objectAtIndex:0] changeText:0]; //arrayIndex is 0

Label *object = [labels objectAtIndex:0];
[object changeText:1];
```

Comment: Code looks fine, and I get no such warning here. Is this the exact code that's giving you the warning?

Comment: Yeah Josh is correct even I tried the code and doesnt give me a warning as well. Please put the exact code which you are using because this doesn't give any warnings.

Comment: My suspicion was correct.  objectAtIndex: returns an NSObject and the compiler can not figure out which changeText: message to apply to it.  Apparently there is some other changeText: floating around in his system which probably takes an NSString*.  You have to cast the NSObject into a Label* before the compiler knows which message to build.  See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow it thinks that changeText: takes a pointer as an argument.  Probably because objectAtIndex: returns an NSObject and Objective-C doesn't know, a priori, what class's signature to apply to it.

Why don't you assign the result of objectAtIndex: to a Label*, *then* apply changeText: to it?

Like so:
Label* label = (Label *)[labels objectAtIndex:0];
[label changeText:1];

Comment: This is a good thought, but `[[labels objectAtIndex:0] changeText:1];` still doesn't give me a warning, even with a third object populating the array, so that the class that owns the array neither imports Label.h nor has an `@class Label` declaration. I don't think we're getting the full story from the OP.

Comment: You have a different build system than he does.  Maybe he's using an older SDK that has a chageText: message that takes an NSString*.

Comment: I can't find a "changeText:" in any search, but you may be right. Re: your example, the cast is unnecessary. `objectAtIndex:` returns `id`, not `NSObject *`.

Comment: You're right.  I had another object that has the changeText method that takes in an NSString.  Is the only way to clear up this ambiguity to cast it?

Comment: Sooner or later you will have to cast it.  At some point the system needs to know which message to build.  As far as it's concerned, you just have a generic <id> [thank you for clarifying that, Josh.  I was too lazy to look it up.].  A selector is built by the argument names, not the types like in C++.

Comment: Can you change the name of the argument?  Something like changeTextIndexed:?  Or else you can cast it in place: [(Label *)[labels objectAtIndex:0] changeText:1];

Answer (score 5):

More likely than not, you aren't `#import`ing the header file containing the definition of `changeText:` into whatever `.m` file is calling it and, thus, the compiler hasn't seen the method declaration and doesn't know what the argumentation is supposed to be.

Or you have a `changeText:` method defined that *does* take an object reference as an argument and the compiler is seeing that before compiling the call site.

Comment: Neither of those are the problem.  Interesting enough though, calling the method in this way does not give an error: [[labels objectAtIndex:0] changeText:0]

Comment: Right, because 0 is a valid pointer, as far as C is concerned.

Comment: Or he didn't declare the `changeText:` method in his header.

Comment: Yah -- it is something basic, though.  The declaration isn't being seen or, if it is, it is not what is shown or there is another signature floating about that is in conflict.   A search of "changeText:" in the project with all versions pasted would help (assuming more than one).  If that doesn't help, it is because the imports are wrong.